# What is the difference between queries and questions in mysql

Tags: mysql, variables, status

I would like to know the difference between below two values in mysql.

```
show status like 'queries' ;
+---------------+-------------+
| Variable_name | Value       |
+---------------+-------------+
| Queries       | 16987383643 |
+---------------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> show status like 'Questions' ;
+---------------+-------+
| Variable_name | Value |
+---------------+-------+
| Questions     | 5     |
+---------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-status-variables.html#statvar_Queries

Comment: I swa this mannual but its not clear to me. When the difference is only about the queries from stored procedures, then why is the huge difference between. please explain in words.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try looking in the manual?

- [13.7.5.37. SHOW STATUS Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-status-variables.html)
- [5.1.5. Server Status Variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-status-variables.html#statvar_Queries)

> unlike the Queries variable. This [Questions] variable does not count COM_PING, COM_STATISTICS, COM_STMT_PREPARE, COM_STMT_CLOSE, or COM_STMT_RESET commands.

Comment: I swa this mannual but its not clear to me. When the difference is only about the queries from stored procedures, then why is the huge difference between. please explain in words.

Comment: Well it's not just about SPs. The bit I said specifically mentions 5 other things.

Comment: i donno what these 5 things mean actually. shall we post some information on these too please...

Comment: Once again, the book is your friend. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/server-status-variables.html#statvar_Com_xxx